# customise oauth_token_access table spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have spring boot with spring security where I maintain Oauth tables like oauth_access_token and oauth_refresh_token.

I have tried to customise the oauth_access_token adding a new column, but I am not able to update the column with the value. it is always null.

Does anyone come across such situation? please share the suggestions.

Comment: Since Spring manages this table itself, how do you try to update the column? Did you create a new Entity?

Comment: Yes the spring manages the table I agree, and yes table is being created by me through liquidbase schema manager. Though I dont have entity class, I use JdbcTokenStore class to insert or update the table.

Comment: So you are injecting JdbcTokenStore? But how do you add something to the token, by extending OAuth2AccessToken? Could you add some example code how you try to add something?

Comment: Hi @Jens I have just realised that the table we are adding the additional information to the token, where it saves as blob type. The additional info will be a map with key values of newly added fields and its values. accessToken.getAdditionalInformation()